# Second Level dropline menu stays active on other pages

Tags: css, joomla, menu

I have a little problem here. I have been kicking myself all day long and decided to ask questions here.
I have a site i developed on Joomla 2.5. I installed a module called dropline menu and i discover some little bugs in it. when the site is on the home page, the menu reveals the sub-menu on mouse hover, but when you select a submenu under any of the parent menu, when the page loads up, the second level menu also display instead of hiding. the only menu that has nothing like that is the career menu.
The Demo site is 
    http://demob.atlastechng.com/unicem/
Please, Try selecting company structure sub-menu under about us and see the menu revealing itself.
How can i hide the sub-menu on opening another page.
All help/assistance would be gladly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Hello Y'all,
I was able to solve the question myself.
I disabled the value of ul#droplinenavigator227.navi li.level1.active ul.level2: Left:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the question myself.
I disabled the value of ul#droplinenavigator227.navi li.level1.active ul.level2: Left:0
Thanks for viewing !